# jsoup - Unable to login

Tags: java, session, cookies, jsoup

I am trying to login to the website given below using jSoup in Java. Although I am providing necessary POST fields, it's still returning login page.

I want to login and parse a page which is available only to logged in users.

```
String id = "myID";
String password = "myPassword";


Connection.Response res2 = Jsoup.connect("http://egov.ddit.ac.in/index.php?r=site/login")
                                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                                .userAgent("Mozilla")
                                .data("LoginForm[username]", id) 

                                .data("LoginForm[password]", password)

                                .followRedirects(true)
                                .execute();

            out.println(res2.parse());
            Connection.Response res3 = Jsoup.connect("http://egov.ddit.ac.in/index.php?r=studentInformation/studentInfo")
                                .cookies(res2.cookies())
                                .userAgent("Mozilla")
                                .data("LoginForm[username]", id) 
                                .data("LoginForm[password]", password)
                                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                                .followRedirects(true)
                                .execute();




            out.println(res3.parse());
```

Both println statements are printing login page only.

I've tried googling for solutions, still didn't find any.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just track actual HTTP traffic with a real browser and them simulate exactly the same programmatically. My cents on that it failed because you forgot the submit button and perhaps a few hidden fields.

Comment: @BalusC As for the flow of website, I'm simulating exactly that. And no, I haven't missed any hidden form fields either. And as for button click, form doesn't have any value associated with submit button. Tried sending empty string and also tried sending button name as value. Both not working.